# Efficient way to store list of partitioned sets in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, database-schema

I have a list of things, each of which has multiple names (call these N) and multiple attributes (A). An example would be a list of pets with nicknames:

```
{ Charles } <-> { goldfish }
{ Fluffy, Mr. Fluffs, Señor Fluffs} <-> { gato, cat, chat, feline }
{ Fido, Buster } <-> {dog, Labrador mix, mutt, brown-haired, chien}
```

I may have many of these, most of which are likely to have just one or two entries in N and A, but which could in principle have a large number of entries. I also need to store a small amount of data about each record, such as the age of each pet and their place of birth.

I will need to retrieve each thing sequentially and have all the data from each set for that thing readily accessible.

Can you propose a strategic way to structure my database table(s)? Two fields with comma-separated values is tempting, but surely I can do better, right? I'm a bit stuck.

Thanks in advance,

Mark C.

Comment: Is the list of all possible attributes predictable?

Comment: Not especially -- we're not going to have, say, a breed and a name in French on every or even most records. They're pretty equivalent in character and weight. Another example could be (deviating from the pets) attributes as flavours, so { grape, cherry, strawberry } for one and {chocolate, vanilla, pineapple, raspberry, orange } for another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would like a normalized database consisting of three tables: one for the pet, one with names and one with attributes. In MySQL:

```
create table pet (
    id int primary key,
    dateOfBirth date,
    placeOfBirth varchar(50)
);

create table name (
    id int references pet (id),
    name varchar(50),
    primary key (id , name)
);

create table attribute (
    id int references pet (id),
    attribute varchar(50),
    primary key (id , attribute)
);

insert into pet (id) values (1);
insert into pet (id) values (2);
insert into pet (id) values (3);

insert into name (id,name) values (1,'Charles');
insert into name (id,name) values (2,'Fluffy');
insert into name (id,name) values (2,'Mr. Fluffs');
insert into name (id,name) values (2,'Señor Fluffs');
insert into name (id,name) values (3,'Fido');
insert into name (id,name) values (3,'Buster');

insert into attribute (id,attribute) values (1,'goldfish');
insert into attribute (id,attribute) values (2,'gato');
insert into attribute (id,attribute) values (2,'cat');
insert into attribute (id,attribute) values (2,'chat');
insert into attribute (id,attribute) values (2,'feline');
insert into attribute (id,attribute) values (3,'dog');
insert into attribute (id,attribute) values (3,'Labrador mix');
insert into attribute (id,attribute) values (3,'mutt');
insert into attribute (id,attribute) values (3,'brown-haired');
insert into attribute (id,attribute) values (3,'chien');
```

If you want an aggregation you can query these tables something like:

```
select 
    group_concat(distinct name
        order by name),
    group_concat(distinct attribute
        order by attribute)
from
    pet
        inner join
    name USING (id)
        inner join
    attribute USING (id)
group by id;
```

Comment: Couldn't `name` just be a column in the `pet` table?

Comment: If the pet only had one name, yes. But here there are multiple names.